# dlopen malloc deadlock

Tags: c, malloc, deadlock, dlopen

We have some unit tests that often deadlock. Closer inspection with GDB reveals the following:

**Thread 1:**

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00110424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00c681a3 in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00bf09fb in _L_lock_515 () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00bf068c in tr_mallochook () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00bece22 in calloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00b5ed93 in _dl_new_object () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#6  0x00b5b287 in _dl_map_object_from_fd () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#7  0x00b5c521 in _dl_map_object () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#8  0x00b66f43 in dl_open_worker () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#9  0x00b629a6 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#10 0x00b66a06 in _dl_open () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#11 0x00d38c3b in dlopen_doit () from /lib/libdl.so.2
#12 0x00b629a6 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#13 0x00d3903c in _dlerror_run () from /lib/libdl.so.2
#14 0x00d38b71 in dlopen@@GLIBC_2.1 () from /lib/libdl.so.2
...
```

**Thread 2:**

```
#0  0x00110424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00d4c059 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00d4740e in _L_lock_752 () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00d4731a in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00c95dd2 in _dl_addr () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00bf0425 in tr_where () from /lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x00bf06bd in tr_mallochook () from /lib/libc.so.6
#7  0x00bed01b in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
....
```

I did a lot of searches on the Internet but I can't really find out whether I am doing something wrong, or whether I have found a bug in the libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

glibc's `dlopen()` code doesn't seem to be thread safe.

It looks like your code calls `malloc()` and `dlopen()` concurrently from two threads. It also looks like `malloc()` call hits an unresolved dynamic symbol and tries to resolve it using `_dl_addr()`, which implies that the binary you are executing was linked with lazy binding (default `ld` behaviour) and this is why the runtime linker resolves symbols on demand on the first call. Try linking it with `-Wl,-z,now` `gcc` linker option to cause the runtime linker resolve all symbols prior to starting your application.

This bug looks similar to the one I filed a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=661676) against.